# TypeError: Cannot compare to non-Duration

Tags: ros, rospy, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to ignore the immediate call to a function. Hence I need to keep track of the time at which the function was invoked. In other words, I want to skip the function call, if the function is being called before defined time.

Below is the code snippet:

```
# define time interval
dt = rospy.Time(secs=2)
old = rospy.Time.now()
# doing some task here
now = rospy.Time.now()
if (now - old < dt):
    print 'Ignoring immediate call'
```

Although, the logic looks fine but the code throws following error at runtime:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare to non-Duration
```

Any workaround, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276110/typeerror:-cannot-compare-to-non-duration/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-11-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the confusion stems from a mixing of ROS `Time` and `Duration` objects. In particular, subtracting two `Time` objects yields a `Duration` object, which cannot be directly compared to another `Time` object. The types of objects created by ROS `Time` & `Duration` arithmetic are explained on the ROS Wiki: 
http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Time_and_Duration_arithmetic

For your example:

```
>>> old = rospy.Time.now()
>>> new = rospy.Time.now()
>>> print type(new - old)
<class 'genpy.rostime.Duration'>
>>> dt = rospy.Time(secs=2)
>>> print type(dt)
<class 'rospy.rostime.Time'>
```

if instead we make `dt` a `rospy.Duration`, the `if` statement can be evaluated:

```
>>> dt = rospy.Duration(secs=2)
>>> print type(dt)
<class 'rospy.rostime.Duration'>
>>> (new - old) < dt
True
```

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2017-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2017-11-16**:
Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I really liked it.

**Comment by [anonymous60874](https://answers.ros.org/users/60874/anonymous60874/) on 2022-04-05**:
I want to get value from .yaml file. When i get the value i encounter this error. How can I fix or is there any solution?